# JMeter Not Recognizing Server Name Field - Test Failed Code Expected To Equal /

Tags: jmeter

My colleague is running the same JMeter file as myself but for some reason it doesn't work for her but it does for me.

She can make it work if instead of having the field Server Name filled in she has the whole url on path instead. 
We've checked all our settings and they seem to be the same (same version of JMeter included). Not sure what we could be missing please?

File that doesn't work

[image]

[image]

File that works

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: on windows it doesn't work? did she updated host file with domain?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes, we're both using windows machines. When she has the server name field empty it works for her if she has the whole url on the path instead. For me it works both ways.

Comment: Check in hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) if the domain exists

Comment: That's what we both have there ```# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#    127.0.0.1       localhost
#    ::1             localhost```

Comment: I have a `vagrant-hostmanager-start id` field at the bottom of the file but she doesn't it.

Comment: Can you add the exception she gets and the request she sent in View Results Listener?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to do when created the question but ended up pasting the same picture twice instead. It's updated now.

Comment: You should remove "/application/api-hc" from the server name and add it to the path field, or have the full URL in the path field as you did in the second time. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's what I wanted to avoid as it would require us editing all the tests for them to run on colleagues's machine. The way it is now it works on mine but now for her. But anyways, may be easier to do this editing than trying to understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake due to which the test is not running.

There is a slash "/" missing in the path "get-event", you should write "/get-event" because jmeter reads the url by combining the link from server field and path field. So, when link joins together it becomes "/api-hcget-even" instead "/api-hc/get-even"

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Tried this but still didn't work for her. Will edit the files as per the second screenshots as both cases work on my machine and may be easier to do this than trying to understand why it's not working. Thanks for trying though.